# Qunit changes to test script not being picked up

Tags: unit-testing, qunit

I set up a new QUnit solution:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>QUnit Example</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/qunit.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      /h1>
    <h2 id="qunit-banner">
    </h2>
    <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
    <ol id="qunit-tests">
    </ol>
      <script src="/resources/js/qunit.js"></script>
      <script src="/resources/tests.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I have a test in my `tests.js` script file:

```
test( "hello test", function() {
  ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
});
```

The test passes, so this setup works.

However when I make changes to `tests.js`, they are not being picked up. For instance, if I add a test, it is not being run. The only way to make the test run is to rename `tests.js` to something else, say `tests2.js`, and update the reference. The changes are then picked up.

Anyone know what's going on and how to fix this so I don't need to keep updating the reference and changing the filename?

Answer (score 1):

I experience a similar problem. It's due to caching. One solution would be to hard refresh your page a bunch of times after every change or just empty the cache. Another would be to add revision numbers to your files so they are freshly loaded every time: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/